# jquery calculate height and width and animate content behind it

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

- animate content behind **h1**
- if **h1** is top of the image don't animate

Currently works fine but I need to calculate the width of the h1 tag as well in order to animate the image just outside the h1.
Basically if the image sits outside the width of the h1 should show.

I hope this is enough clear.
[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/33Ec8/)

js:

```
// Get the divs that should change
function displayThese() {
    var $heading = $('h1');
    var h1top = $heading.position().top;
    var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();

    var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();

        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top;
    });
    return divs;
}

(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divs = displayThese();
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    // Get items that do not change    
    var divs = $('li').not(displayThese());
    divs.css({
        opacity: .3
    });
});
```

Comment: so you need the width of the h1 tag?

Comment: Yes I this so. If the width is what is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use [`$.fn.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) :

```
var $heading = $('h1');
var h1top = $heading.position().top;
var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
var h1left = $heading.position().left;
var h1right = h1top + $heading.width();

var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
    var $e = $(this);
    var top = $e.position().top;
    var bottom = top + $e.height();
    var left = $e.position().left;
    var right = left + $e.width();

    return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top || left > h1right || right < h1left;
});
return divs;
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/33Ec8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
$(<element>).width()
$(<element>).height()
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/33Ec8/2/).

Comment: Based on my function, how can I implement that on the displayThese function?